# Changing program used to open file based on file extension

Tags: linux-mint, file-types

For a college class, I have to download and open .rkt files. In order to open them with the correct program I have to right-click > open with, and if I set a default program, it becomes the default for all text files. Is there any way to change the default just for files ending in .rkt. (Similar to the way python files open in atom when they end in .py but open in xed when they do not, even though `file` still recognizes them as python files.)

Comment: Linux doesn't really recognize extension types the way Windows does so the environment you're using is probably handling it. Try 'mimeopen -d file.rkt' command. Are you using Xfce? You could install and run thunar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new mimetype for it.
First create a `text-rkt.xml` file with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
    <mime-type type="text/rkt">
        <comment>rkt text</comment>
        <generic-icon name="leafpad"/>
        <glob pattern="*.rkt"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Then add this to local mime database:

```
xdg-mime install text-rkt.xml
```

Then associate with some program (e.g. leafpad):

```
xdg-mime default leafpad.desktop text/rkt
```

And voila: all .rkt files will be opened in leafpad. (and their icon is also leafpad)